# Prove that the Characteristic function of discrete random variable is bounded and continuous on $[0,1]$

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

Let a random variable $\xi$ take values in $\mathbb Z_+$ and $\mathbb E \xi \lt \infty $. How do  I prove that the characteristic function $\psi _\xi$ is bounded and continuous on $[0,1].$

**My Attempt:** The discrete RV characteristic function looks like $$\psi_\xi (t) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{itk} P(\xi= k).$$
So taking values from $\mathbb Z_+$ where $x_1 \leq x_2$ then $x_{1}^k \leq x_{2}^k$ for all $k\in \mathbb Z_+$. The function $\psi_\xi (x)$  can be written as: $$\psi_\xi (x_1) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{1}^k p(\xi=k) \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{2}^k p(\xi=k)  = \psi_\xi (x_2).$$
Therefore the function $\psi_\xi (x)$  cis an increasing function. But I am stuck here, how do I show that it is bounded and continuous on $[0,1]$. Any help or hint is appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What do you mean with $X_n$ here? Should it not be $\xi$ instead. Further $\psi_{\xi}(t)$ is a function on $\mathbb R$ (not on $[0,1]$).

Comment: the convergence of $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}e^{itk}\Pr [\xi =k]$ is trivial as it converges absolutely (to one)

Comment: $\psi_\xi (t)$ is complex.  How can it be increasing?

Comment: You are mixing things up. Have a good look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Properties).

Comment: Thanks for the observation here the first formula  $\psi_\xi (t)$given was just a trivial case I used to guide me in the problem

Comment: Not related to the proble @drhab

Comment: The second equality $\psi_{\xi}(x_1)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x_1^kp(\xi=k)$ is unclear to me. I would expect something like $\psi_{\xi}(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{itk}p(\xi=k)$. That is the characteristic function for r.v. $\xi$.

Comment: @drhab you might be right. Like I said earlier, I'm stuck... It was just an attempt I made. Any better approach is appreciated.

Comment: Observe that $$\left|\psi_{\xi}\left(t\right)\right|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{itk}p\left(\xi=k\right)\right|\leq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left|e^{itk}p\left(\xi=k\right)\right|=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p\left(\xi=k\right)=1$$
showing immediately that function $\psi_{\xi}\left(t\right)$ is bounded. You can show continuity e.g. by showing that $t_{n}\to t$ implies $\psi_{\xi}\left(t_{n}\right)\to\psi_{\xi}\left(t\right)$.